# `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data` when reading certain objects from file

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have some very basic serialization code:

```
void serializeObjectToFile(Serializable serializable, File file) {
    ObjectOutputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        stream.writeObject(serializable);
        stream.flush();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.error("Failed to serialize object: {}.", serializable, exception);
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                logger.error("Error closing stream.", exc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also some very deserialization code:

```
Object deserializeObjectFromFile(File file) {
    ObjectInputStream oiStream = null;
    try {
        oiStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        return oiStream.readObject();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        logger.error("Exception loading object from file '{}'.", file.getAbsolutePath(), exc);
    } finally {
        if (oiStream != null) {
            try {
                oiStream.close();
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                logger.error("Error closing stream.", exc);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This code works fine for most objects. But for some objects I get the following exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at my.CustomClass.deserializeObjectFromFile(CustomClass.java:79) ~[classes/:na]
```

I do not try to serialize more than one object per file (as suggested by other questions on the topic). The code works for most objects, but not for some. Since `ArrayList.readObject()` appears in the stack trace: has that got something to do with the problem? If so, what? To my surprise and dismay I found nothing on the net concerning that problem...

I appreciate any pointers on where to go from here...!

Comment: What's it an ArrayList *of?* ArrayList itself is practically certain not to be the culprit here, but a class of your own with a custom readObject()/writeObjext() pair definitely is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: One of the objects deep down in the object graph implemented the following method:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
```

without actually writing its internals to the `ObjectOutputStream` and without throwing an exception (the method was implemented for validation purposes). So the solution: when implementing this method, either throw an `Exception` of some sort or write the internals of the object to the `ObjectOutputStream`. Easiest is to call

```
out.defaultWriteObject();
```